# Same redirect_to route that worked for post does not work for comment (same url)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following post controller:

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @post = @book.posts.create(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book), notice: "Success!~"
  else 
    redirect_to book_path(@book), alert: "Failure!" 
  end       
end
```

Exactly same `redirect_to` is used for comments. Comment creation form and list are on the same url as the post creation form and list (which is show.html.erb for book)

comments controller create:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book), notice: "Success!~"
  else 
    redirect_to book_path(@book), alert: "Failure!" 
  end   
end
```

But when I create a comment, this error shows: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`. The comment is created and saved in the database.

I have tried `book` and `book.id` instead of `@book`. None worked. (interestingly, from books list to `show.html.erb`, I can only go there by `book_path(book.id)` and not `book_path(@book)`).

Here's my book show action, and below it is my show.html.erb for book.

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@post = @book.posts.new
@comment = Comment.new
```

show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@book, @book.posts.build]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit "Post"%>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% @book.posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>
    <%= @book.title %>
    <%= post.text %>
  </p>
  <%= form_for(post.comments.build, url: "/posts/#{post.id}/comments") do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit "Post comment"%>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :books, shallow: true 
end

resources :books do
  resources :posts, shallow: true
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

Comment: You have `book_path(@book)` but `@book` is not defined in your create method. You need `book_path(@post.book)` instead

Comment: @escanxr Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, you are not supplying an id for the book.  Notice how the show route is something like `/books/2` where `2` is the id?  That number is not getting supplied in the comments controller.  It looks to me like comments belong to a post which belongs to a book, so this should solve the issue for you.

```
if @comment.save
  redirect_to book_path(@post.book.id), notice: "Success!~"
else 
  redirect_to book_path(@post.book.id), alert: "Failure!" 
end
```

In your code you are using `@book` but it does not look like you ever set that variable with any values the way you do in the `create` method, so there is no `id` value there, make sense?

Comment: Worked, thank you! If you get a chance, if you could please also answer this I'd really appreciate it... the comments are not showing with this code in show.html.erb: ```<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <%= comment.text %>
  </p>
  <% end %>```

Comment: Did you verify that there is text for the comment getting saved?  does it show anything if you put `comment.id` instead?  What is the output of `<%= @post.comments.count %>`?

Comment: ```<%= @post.comments.count %>``` returns 0 for each post. comments are saved in the database (via SQL)... not sure why.

Comment: .inspect returns ```#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>``` for each comment on each post

Comment: So there is your problem, there are no comments to show according to your current data.  Best of luck!  Sounds like you are in a loop, are you sure is does not need to be `post` without the `@`?

Comment: You have solved it with your last comment! post without the @ worked. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose that's because it's local

Comment: It worked because in the loop you are likely setting that as the variable like this `|post|` right?  So the word inside the two lines is the variable, make sense (or you already knew that?)?

Comment: This makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much!